# After modifying my profile picture it appears as a black square

Tags: support, profile-picture

I am trying to modify my profile picture. In my profile I can update it with a new picture:

[image]

[image]

But after a save it shows only a black square:

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing in the process?

This appear to be due to the resize feature of Imgur which munge transparent to black. Is there a way to add a transparent image today?

Comment: Is your picture by any chance black on transparent?

Comment: Yes it's black on transparent.

Comment: The accepted answer says the issue has been fixed on his post.

Comment: If you read comments on the dupe you can see it was never really fixed, or at least not for long, it certainly still happens now anyway

Comment: @Cai yes so what's the process, call it a bug? Ask a new question?

Comment: This is a bug on imgur side, where sometimes (not always) the thumbnail creation cause transparent image to be black. You just have to re-upload, until it works. e.g. I [uploaded it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ToD.png), and [the thumbnail this time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ToD.png?s=32&g=1) works fine.

Comment: @Cai well, "sometimes" is better than "never". I won't call it a fix, just making something bad a bit better. But still, trying enough times should work...

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a starnge behaviour, with your image (the re-upload) it kind of works (the picture is cropped), but with mine it still do the black square.